# how to execute procedure which has out varchar

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I have a package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack1
AS
    procedure proc1(column_1 in table1.column1%TYPE, column_2 in table1.column2%TYPE, results out varchar)

//code....
......
.....
....//
    END pack1;
/
```

I want to know how to execute this procedure. I know it's a silly question, But I am very confused about this.
I tried this: `exec pack1.proc1(123,'abc')`
But this is not working. Please tell me how to execute this

Answer (score 2):

You may use a   bind variable in SQL* Plus to get the results and display it using `PRINT`

```
VARIABLE v_result VARCHAR2
EXECUTE pack1.proc1(123, 'abc', :v_result); --note the colon.
PRINT v_result   --display the results.
```

If you're calling it from a PL/SQL block or another procedure, you may just display it using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_results VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
 pack1.proc1(123, 'abc', l_results);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_results);
END;
/
```

**Note**: Use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` as the datatype for procedure parameter `results`